# How to convert passport.authenticate username to lower case before submitting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm using passport in my nodejs app for authentication like so

```
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/",
    failureRedirect: "/login"
}), function (req, res) {

})
```

and I'm having a problem because I don't know how to convert a person's username to lowercase since when they register I convert their usernames to all lowercase using `.toLowerCase()` before storing in my database.

How can I do the same thing when they enter their username for the login?

Comment: You could do it client-side on form submit. Something like the answer to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894328/convert-input-text-to-lowercase-on-submitting-a-form

Comment: @RunnyYolk I know various ways of doing it on the client side but I am interested in doing it to on the server side before it is submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add middleware that runs before passport's action

```
router.post("/login", usernameToLowerCase, passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/",
    failureRedirect: "/login"
}), function (req, res) {

});
function usernameToLowerCase(req, res, next){
    req.body.username = req.body.username.toLowerCase();
    next();
}
```