# Lowercase the input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, routes

I have an input, submitting it, form "actions" to another page with parameter, that equals this input.

But I need to lowercase the input before it is gone to the parameter.
How can I do this?

No CSS code...

```
<form action='board.html'>
                <h2 align="left">Введите имя пользователя:</h2>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
                    <input id="golos-username-search" ng-change="golosBoard.username_lowercase()" type="text" name="user" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" placeholder="Имя пользователя">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default"  type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Even if i'll type "QWERTY", link must be like this:

```
link.com/board.html?user=qwerty
```

Comment: @Daryuska. There is a similar question, answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894328/convert-input-text-to-lowercase-on-submitting-a-form?rq=1)

Comment: Add `onsubmit="validate(this)"` to your `<form>` and add the function. Inside, change the input's value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it. Depends on what you prefer. Here are some ideas:

Change the text to lowercase on fly like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="text" ng-change="text = text.toLowerCase()">
```

Or use a `$watch` in your controller to watch the input variable:

```
$scope.$watch('text', function(val) {
   $scope.text= $filter('lowercase')(val);
}, true);`
```

or the approach @JVM has mentioned in the comment where you convert the text to lowercase before you submit your form.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase

You can call toLowerCase on the string before putting it into the link